# What's is the preferred way of loading azure blobs directly into pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, azure, blob

I would like to explore .tsv files directly from blob storage using azure sdk12 python library.

Currently, I am using the following pattern:

```
from io import BytesIO
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd

with BytesIO() as bytestream:
    blob_client.download_blob().download_to_stream(bytestream)
    bytestream.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_table(bytestream)
```

However, this strikes me as a somewhat wordy option. Is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to download tsv file into pandas dataframes.

One is the code in your issue, which downloads to the **stream** and then reads stream into df. Refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10782#issuecomment-612111690).

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

with BytesIO() as input_blob:
    blob_client.download_blob().download_to_stream(input_blob)
    input_blob.seek(0)
    DF = pd.read_table(input_blob)
```

Another is downloading to the **file path**, then reading the path.

```
fpath = ""
with open(fpath, "wb") as download_file:
    download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
    
df = pd.read_table(fpath, delim_whitespace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work